# Throwing exceptions as strings in v8

Tags: javascript, v8

In our application, I am constructing an exception object as under:

```
auto exception = v8::Object::New(isolate_);
exception->Set(code_name, code_value);
```

This exception is thrown using the call: `isolate_->ThrowException(exception);`

On the console and in logs, when we are printing the exception, we see an object instead of exception message. Below is the seen output:

```
[object Object]
```

How can we see the exception message as string instead of object?

Comment: not familiar with embedded, but maybe access the .message property of the exception / object?

Comment: Why not use `v8::Exception`?

Comment: @robertklep My input to throw exception is an v8::Object. It contains may fields like code_name (I have only put one here). So, I am not sure how to use v8::Exception here as the input to v8::Exception should be a string handle

Answer (score 0):

**From Javascript**, you can print the exception to the console using `JSON.stringify(exception)`. So your Javascript code would look like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
}
```

You should then see the full object as a String in the console, like this:

```
{ "message": "An error occurred.", "code": 123 }
```

With this information, you can easily find the message (and other information) inside the exception object.

**From C++**, you can also call `JSON.stringify()`:

```
Handle<Object> json = Context::GetCurrent()->Global()->Get(String::New("JSON"))->ToObject();
Handle<Function> stringify = Handle<Function>::Cast(json->Get(String::New("stringify")));
```

Then you can call that function with the exception object as a parameter, like this:

```
stringify->Call(json, 1, exception);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This exception is also dumped to logs. Sorry for not mentioning earlier. How to solve this problem when dumping the exception to logs as we can not use JSON.stringify() in C++ code.